# Extending geometry of one MultiLine shapefile alongside the geometry of another MultiLine shapefile in Qgis 3.16.5

Tags: qgis, shapefile, nodetool

I'm trying to extend segments of one polyline shapefile from the intersecting point wit another multiline feature alongside the vertices of this secon line feature. For this I'm using the nod tool, by clicking each vertix point individualy. Is there a better and faster solution to this?

Here is a YouTube link to me explaining my problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8KLG4BCOcDY